# Pandas DataFrame - insert copy of row with some changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'B':[10, 20, 30, 44, 48, 81]})
```

And I want to insert a copy of the row `x[5]`, but in it add +2 to 'A' value, +7 to 'B' value. How can I do this?

Obviously in the real example the dataframe has many more columns, that's why it makes sense for me to copy a row rather than manually populate the value for each column in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First build the dataframe for then one you need creat the copy from original dataframe, the we adjust the value in it , then `concat` it back

```
x1=x.loc[[5],:]
x1.A+=2
x1.B+=7
x_new = pd.concat([x,x1]).sort_index()
x_new
Out[291]: 
   A   B
0  1  10
1  2  20
2  3  30
3  4  44
4  5  48
5  6  81
5  8  88
```

Comment: How do I make sure that the index has a different value? Seems like you got 5 in both rows, this could be a problem.

Comment: @BaronYugovich after filter the row need to be changed , `x1.index=range(x.index.max()+1,x.index.max()+len(x1)+1)
`